# Initialize a static member of a class that includes an array?

Tags: c++, initialization, static-members

I have a C++ class with a static data member which is a constant. I added an array to the class definition, and now I get an error when trying to initialize the static member.

Here is the code:

```
class MyClass
{

int i1;
int i2;
int i3;
//bool b1[2];
//bool b2[2];

public:
    //Constructors
    MyClass();
    MyClass(const int i1In, const int i2In, const int i3In
        /*, const bool b1In[2], const bool b2In[2]*/
        );
// Copy constructor
MyClass(const Input& rhs);

// Destructor
~MyClass();

// Assignment
MyClass& operator=(const MyClass& rhs);

// Operators
bool operator==(const MyClass& m2) const;
bool operator!=(const MyClass& m2) const;
MyClass& operator++(int/*serves no purpose, but must be included*/);

static const MyClass S;
};

const MyClass S = { 0, 0, 0 /*,{ false,false }, { false,false }*/ };
```

The above code compiles without error, and the value of `S` is as expected. However, when I change the class definition to add the arrays `b1` and `b2` (uncomment two places in the class defn and add two array initializers in the initialization of `S`), I get the error

"C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'initializer list' to 'MyClass'
 note: No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous".

What is the proper way to define a constant variable of type `MyClass` that has the indicated values?

Windows 7 Pro, Visual Studio 2015

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have the constructor take the array parameters by constant reference.

```
MyClass(/*...*/ const bool (&b1In)[2], const bool (&b2In)[2])

const MyClass MyClass::S(/*...*/ { false,false }, { false,false } );
```

The array-as-parameter syntax is really just a cleverly disguised pointer which is why that didn't work.

Also, your `operator++(int)` returns a reference. Because that is the post-increment operator, it should return by value.

Comment: The array params by const reference seems to work, although I must admit I don't understand it. But in the original code (without the bool arrays), I created a global constant of type MyClass; in this version, I must specify MyClass::S instead of just S.

Comment: @Woody20 I'm less sure of how arrays work in regards to temporaries and references, so I didn't want to put this in the answer. But I'm pretty sure it works because it creates a temporary array, initializes it with the braced init-list, and then binds that to the reference. That's how it would work with an aggregate type, anyway.